# How to open graphql playground page using apollo server express in 2022?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-server

We have a API project using express with Apollo server express and graphql, I am new to graphql so I don't know how to land graphql playground page by default.
when I am trying to run it lands on "http://localhost:8080/graphql but it shows

**The full landing page can not be loaded; it appears that you might be offline**

can any one help me how to land graphql playground page?

I have followed the below code

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');


const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello world!',
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const port = 8080;

app.listen({ port }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${port}${server.graphqlPath}`),
);
```

Comment: The playground relies on being able to open https://studio.apollographql.com/ in your browser, which requires a working internet connection.

Comment: then what is the use of http://localhost:8080/graphql ? this is the API end point right

Comment: Yes, that's the API endpoint, which you can use from a GraphQL client. However, the playground doesn't run locally (although it uses your local API to perform queries against). If you want to run a local playground, take a look at [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) or, if you happen to run macOS, [GraphQL Playground](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-playground).

Answer (score 1):

Install apollo-server-core and add {ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground} it from the plugin section

source
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/plugin/landing-pages/